# Transferring Data from CollectionView inside TableView to a New ViewController

Tags: uitableview, swift3, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, delegates

So I have a main ViewController that has Horizontal Scrolling CollectionViews inside a TableView. When you click on an Item in the CollectionView it transfers all the data from the Item to a new ViewController to display it properly.

The problem I am facing is when you click on the item in the CollectionView a segue is performed that transfers data to an array in the new ViewController but instead of transferring only data from the particular item it send data from more than one item. On some debugging I also found that the items Custom class is what loads the multiple elements in the array and not the segue. Here is some code.

**cellForRowAt in main VC**

```
if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeadlineRow", for: indexPath) as? HeadlineRow {

    cell.latest = self.latest
    cell.collectionView.reloadData()
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
}
```

**Segue Code in main VC**

```
func pushToNewsVC(latestNews: [LatestNews]) {
    self.transferToNewsVC = latestNews
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "NewsVC", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "NewsVC" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? NewsVC  {
            destination.latestNews.append(contentsOf: self.transferToNewsVC)
            destination.SuggestedLatestNews.append(contentsOf: self.latest)
        }
    }
}
```

**Headlinerow which is TableViewCell class**

```
var latest = [LatestNews]()
var transferData = [LatestNews]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return latest.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HeadlineCell", for: indexPath) as? HeadlineCell {

        let latest = self.latest[indexPath.row]
        cell.updateUI(latest: latest)
        return cell
    }
    return UICollectionViewCell()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? HeadlineCell {
        self.transferData.removeAll()
        self.transferData = cell.transferData
        delegate?.pushToNewsVC(latestNews: self.transferData)
    }
}
```

**HeadlineCell which is CollectioViewCell class**

```
var transferData = [LatestNews]()

func updateUI(latest: LatestNews) {
    storyTextView.text = latest.headline
    self.thumbnail.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(latest.app_img)"))
    self.transferData.append(latest)
}
```